# How to do paging in datagrid asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I can't get paging to work in my DataGrid even though I set `AllowPaging="true"` and `AllowCustomPaging="true"`

[image]

It was working earlier but now I don't know what happened.

What do I need to change in order to make it work?

Comment: stupid question, are enough records even displaying to allow for the possibility of paging?

Comment: Yes , peroija is right , make sure that you have enough records for paging to be available. You can not have paging with page count=1 .

Comment: I have solved my problem neway

Comment: please post your solution below as an answer and then accept as the answer. this allows users to find the solution faster and lets others know you don't need help anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set `datagrid1.VirtualItemCount`, as explained on [msdn – DataGrid.VirtualItemCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.virtualitemcount.aspx), to the actual number of items in my data source since `CustomPaging` does not work without it.

So I added

```
datagrid1.VirtualItemCount = 200;
```

and it worked.